# tagging list of friends in facebook api

Tags: ajax, facebook, jquery, facebook-graph-api

First I get my friend list, select 5 friends and try to tag them in a status update. However, nothing posts. i'm sure the error is here  { tags: tags } or tags += + friend["id"] + ",";
I'm trying to separate each ID wit ha comma and put the whole thing under the tags variable

```
FB.api('/me/friends?access_token=<?php echo $tkn;?>', function(response) {
                            var friends = response["data"];
                            for(var i = 0, n = friends.length; i < n; i++)
                            {
                                var j = Math.round(Math.random() * (n - 1));
                                var fj = friends[j];
                                var fi = friends[i];
                                friends[j] = fi;
                                friends[i] = fj;
                            }
                            var commentsCount = Math.min(friends.length, 5);
                            var commenter = function(commentsLeft) {
                                if(commentsLeft == 0)
                                    Step2();
                                else
                                {
                                    var mentionsCount = Math.min(commentsLeft, 5);
                                    commentsLeft -= mentionsCount;

                                    for(i = 0; i < mentionsCount; i++)
                                    {
                                        var friend = friends.pop();
                                        tags += + friend["id"] + ",";
                                    }
                                    FB.api("/me/feed?place=132738745815&message=look%20here&access_token=<?php echo $tkn;?>", "post", { tags: tags }, function(response) {
                                        commenter(commentsLeft);
                                    });
                                }
                            };
                            commenter(commentsCount); 
                        });
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for your problem to be resolved you should add all parameters to the POST body.

Example:

```
FB.api("/me/feed", "post", { place: "132738745815", tags: tags, message: "look here", access_token: "<?php echo $tkn;?>" }, function(response) {
  commenter(commentsLeft);
});
```

Good luck!